# Ubuntu Server cannot boot - HDD problems

Tags: boot, grub2, raid5

I have major problem, my Ubuntu Server won't start up after reboot, guys in Hetzner datacenter started recsue sistem up and found out this on sda:

```
-----------------%<-----------------
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   036    Pre-fail  Always
FAILING_NOW 4095
-----------------%<-----------------
```

There are **3 x 1.5TB HDDs in RAID5 and on sda there was boot loader**.
They insisted to replace sda with new HDD, so I confirmed.
After that they mailed me back with another thing, **sdc is also corrupted...**
Until 7:30 this morning everything worked fine. After that server has been frozen, and after reboot two HDD-s are corrupted... little bit weird, but no time to think about that.

They `returned corrupted sda back`, so "that I can restore some data..." but the problem is I was stuck.
I tried to mount sdb while in **live-rescue-system and to install grub**, but there is this error:

```
root@rescue ~ # grub-install /dev/sdb
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is
/dev mounted?).
root@rescue ~ # mkdir /media/sdb
root@rescue ~ # mount /dev/sdb /media/sdb
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root@rescue ~ # mount /dev/sdb /media/sdb -t auto
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root@rescue ~ # mount /dev/sdb /media/sdb -t ext3
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
         missing codepage or helper program, or other error
         In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
         dmesg | tail  or so
```

Can someone please help me to try and start Ubuntu server or to somehow restore data from any of disks...

Extra info:

```
root@rescue ~ # ll /dev/sd
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  0 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/sda
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  1 Nov 18 14:06 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8,  2 Nov 18 14:06 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 16 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 17 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 18 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/sdb2
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 8, 32 Nov 18 14:06 /dev/sdc


root@rescue ~ # df -h
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs               12G  3.0M   12G   1% /
udev                 12G     0   12G   0% /dev
188.40.24.212:/nfs  1.4T  592G  722G  46% /root/.oldroot/nfs
aufs                 12G  3.0M   12G   1% /
tmpfs               2.4G  264K  2.4G   1% /run
tmpfs               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs               4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/shm


root@rescue ~ # ll /dev/loo*
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   0 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop0
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   1 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop1
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   2 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop2
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   3 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop3
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   4 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop4
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   5 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop5
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   6 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop6
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   7 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop7
crw------T 1 root root 10, 237 Nov 18 14:04 /dev/loop-control

root@rescue ~ # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cdbda

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            3906     1060289      528192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         1060290  2930272064  1464605887+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c5b77

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            3906     1060289      528192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         1060290  2930272064  1464605887+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 540 MB, 540803072 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 132032 cylinders, total 1056256 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
root@rescue ~ # cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : inactive sda2[0](S)
      1464605760 blocks

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      528128 blocks [3/1] [U__]

unused devices: <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only mount **partitions**, not entire **devices**. A device – usually named *sdx* if it's a SATA drive – can hold several partitions – named after the device they are on with an added number, like *sdx1* for the first partition on *sdx*.

In your case, try `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/partition1` and `mount /dev/sdb2 /media/partition2`, obviously after creating those two directories.

Comment: I managed to do this:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/boot-part
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot-part
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot-part /dev/sdb`


And rebooted, tech guy said:
`As requested we've checked your server and your server is currently booted up into
the grub bash like command prompt.
We can offer you to connect a LARA Remote Console so that you can investigate further.`


So I requested it, and waiting for login data...


What can I do next, how to fix HDD problems? sda & sdc are corupted, sdc isn't even recognized...

Comment: here you have smartctl output on sdc, sdb & sda
http://pastebin.com/wLzh5vdz